# How to use liblbfgs for fitting?

Tags: optimization

I am trying to use [bfgs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm) algorithm in order to fit a set of $\{(x,y),f(x,y)\}$ to a function in the form of let's say $a\cdot cos(x)+b \cdot y=f(x,y)$.

I try to understand how to use bfgs algorithm with [liblbfgs](http://www.chokkan.org/software/liblbfgs/group__liblbfgs__api.html), but I don't understand the [example](http://www.chokkan.org/software/liblbfgs/)  and it is not clear what function the author tried to fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is doing a 100-dimensional (see #define N 100 in the code) optimization. The author is only printing the first two dimensions of x = (x[0],x[1],...,x[N]) as shown below for iteration 1.

```
Iteration 1:
fx = 254.065298, x[0] = -1.069065, x[1] = 1.053443
xnorm = 10.612828, gnorm = 325.365479, step = 0.000607
```

Now f(x) is defined in the function *evaluate*.

```
for (i = 0;i < n;i += 2) {
    lbfgsfloatval_t t1 = 1.0 - x[i];
    lbfgsfloatval_t t2 = 10.0 * (x[i+1] - x[i] * x[i]);
    g[i+1] = 20.0 * t2;
    g[i] = -2.0 * (x[i] * g[i+1] + t1);
    fx += t1 * t1 + t2 * t2;
}
```

fx is for the function value at $x$ and $g(x)$ is a $N\times 1$ (or $100\times 1$) dimensional gradient.

\begin{align}
f(x) = \sum_{i=0,2,4,...,N-2}(1-x_i)^2 + \left(10(x_{i+1} - x_i^2)\right)^2
\end{align}
The gradient at odd components ($i=1,3,5,...$) is
$$200(x_{i+1} - x_i^2) $$
The gradient component at even coordinates ($i=0,2,4,6,...$) is 
$$-2(1-x_i) - 400*x_i*(x_{i+1} - x_i^2)$$

*Note*:

1. indexing starts from 0
2. I believe the gradients in the code are incorrect. When I change the appropriate line g[i+1] = 20.0 * t2; to g[i+1] = 200.0 * t2; I am getting a different answer. Potentially I may be making a mistake here. Nonetheless, hopefully I have answered your question.

**Our fitting problem**
In our case, we have a two dimensional problem. Rename our $f(x,y)$ to $z$. Then, we have an $m\times 3$ dimensional matrix of values with each row being a tuple $(x_j,y_j,z_j), j=1,...,m$ which are fixed. We could now minimize the function $h(a,b)$
\begin{align}
h(a,b) = \sum_{j=1}^{m}(a\cos(x_j) +b y_j - z_j)^2
\end{align}
With
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial h(a,b)}{\partial a} = -2\sum_{j=1}^{m}\left((a\cos(x_j) +b y_j - z_j)\sin(x_j)\right)\\
\frac{\partial h(a,b)}{\partial b} = 2\sum_{j=1}^{m}\left((a\cos(x_j) +b y_j - z_j)y_j\right) 
\end{align}
as the gradient functions.
All that you need to do is encode these in place of the for loop above, change #define N 100 to 2 and initialize some initial value of $a,b$ to be passed into the lbfgs function.

Comment: Any suggestion of how to initialize the `lbfgs_malloced` array?

Comment: Since the documentation notes *A user does not have to use this function for libLBFGS built without SSE/SSE2 optimization*, I assume you want to have SSE optimization? Hmm, I have not explored it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a library I am currently using in a project, and I wanted to add some input to this in case - I cannot add a comment with out a reputation of 50.

I believe that the creator of this library was using the Rosenbrock function as a test, this is a common function used to test unconstrained optimization problems.

Here's a Wikipedia article on the function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function

It's important to note, that for your own application, you need to create your own evaluation function to calculate the gradient of your function at that point.

Comment: Since you added this as an answer, & since you do have some relevant information here, why not expand it into a real answer? Otherwise, it may be deleted.