# Solve ARIMA using L-BFGS

Tags: arima

I want to optimally solve for ARIMA coeffs.
Following the logic in this post:[ARIMA estimation by hand](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77663/arima-estimation-by-hand)

Except I want to use an external BFGS solver (not R's optim function).
So I am using libLBFGS which has a very helpful sample program optimizing a Rosenbach 'Banana Function'.

However the key part of the sample code defines a objective function and gradients (following on this post:[How to use liblbfgs for fitting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73005/how-to-use-liblbfgs-for-fitting))

The 'key' piece from sample.c:

```
for (i = 0;i < n;i += 2) {
    lbfgsfloatval_t t1 = 1.0 - x[i];
    lbfgsfloatval_t t2 = 10.0 * (x[i+1] - x[i] * x[i]);
    g[i+1] = 20.0 * t2;
    g[i] = -2.0 * (x[i] * g[i+1] + t1);
    fx += t1 * t1 + t2 * t2;
}
```

This defined a objective function defined by all your x parameters.
As well as a vector of gradients the same size as the number of variables.
I am confused on how to connect these two posts.
I can define my objective function easily enough in the case of solving MLE for ARIMA coeffs. But I do not understand what I am suppose to do for figuring out the gradients at each iteration. My lin alg is rusty so I am having trouble figuring out where to start.

Any help would be much appreciated.